# GLSL vertex shader breaks when trying to access gl_Position

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

In trying to create a weak depth effect for a wireframe model, where distance from the camera plane changes the colour, I first tried

```
gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
color = vec4(0.0f,pow(2.0f, -gl_Position.z),0.0f,1.0f);
```

However this would render the wireframe entirely black, with the edges of it touching the edges of the window and my camera controls would have no effect.
However if I instead recalculate the depth when calculating the colour vector i.e.

```
color = vec4(0.0f,pow(2.0f, -(camMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0)).z),0.0f,1.0f);
```

everything works fine. Is accessing gl_Position invalid in some way? This is with version 330 core for GLSL

The entire shader file is

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 camMatrix;


void main()
{   
    gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    color = vec4(0.0f,pow(2.0f, -(camMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0)).z),0.0f,1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Does `camMatrix` contain the perspective projection? If so, you are missing the perspective divide, otherwise, you are calculating the view space position and not the projected position. In both cases, the calculation is not the same as `gl_Position.z`.

Comment: The actual maths doesn't matter to me that much right now, its just that `camMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0).z` works while `gl_position.z` doesn't, despite them being the same as far as I can tell

Comment: I understand that, but the two things are not the same. z after projection and perspective divide is normalized, while it's in OpenGL units before the projection.

Comment: @Comma If `camMatrix` is a perspective projection matrix, you are wrong.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I guess that makes my question "Why is `gl_Position.z` not what I expect it to be and how is it so wildly different that it breaks the shader?". Remember, I don't care about the actual values other than far away being a different colour to close.

Comment: @Comma `gl_Position` is a [Homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). Yu have to do a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) to get a [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Surely `gl_Position.z` will still be some number though (can it be negative?), so surely when I take 2 to the power of it, I'll get some result and everything should be fine. The coordinate system shouldn't really matter in any case

Comment: I have to agree with @Comma here. The other comments so far are besides the point of the question (although they make a valid point about the dubious use of clip space z for this calculation), but both variants shown in the question _should_ yield the same result (no matter how useful that result is in practice).